# How to use mutiple attributes (including a partial string match) with find_elements in Selenium for Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Currently I have this line of code which correctly selects this type of object on the webpage I'm trying to manipulate with Selenium:

```
pointsObj = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'treeImg')
```

What I need to do is add in a partial string match condition as well which looks in the section "CLGV (AHU-01_ahu_ChilledWtrVlvOutVolts)" in the line below.

```
<span class="treeImg v65point" style="cursor:pointer;">CLGV (AHU-01_ahu_ChilledWtrVlvOutVolts)</span>
```

I found online there's the ChainedBy option but I can't think of how to reference that text in the span. Do I need to use XPath? I tried that for a second but I couldn't think of how to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refering both the *`CLASS_NAME`* and the *`innerText`* you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- *xpath* using the classname *`treeImg`* and partial innerText:

  ```
  pointsObj = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[contains(@class, 'treeImg') and contains(., 'AHU-01_ahu_ChilledWtrVlvOutVolts')]")
  ```
- *xpath* using all the classnames and entire innerText:

  ```
  pointsObj = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='treeImg v65point' and text()='CLGV (AHU-01_ahu_ChilledWtrVlvOutVolts)']")
  ```

Comment: How would I modify it to be a partial string match instead of exact? This looks really close.

Comment: Check the first option :)

Comment: PERFECT. Thank you so much I've been banging my head against the on this for hours. Now last thing. This function I'm writing needs several loops matching a list of partial strings, could I do something like replace that XPATH string with an f' string containing my variable I'm using to loop over the list?

Comment: @TylerMoore Ofcoarse yes.